# MySQL sharding and stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sharding, mysql-fabric

Is there a way to dispatch stored procedure invocation on particular shard, based on sharding key (passed as procedure argument or somehow separately)?

For example we have a table, sharded between 3 nodes using HASH sharding strategy. All rows with key `A` are stored on `node 1`. I'd like to be sure that when I run `procedure(A)`, it applies on `node1`.

We are going to use Mysql Fabric tool, but other options considered as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the wall...

1. Turn the Procedure into a function.  Simply return `0`, or something irrelevant.
2. Instead of `CALLing` the Procedure, invoke the Function this way:

   `SELECT 0 WHERE key = 'A' AND routine(key);`

The hope is that the sharding will kick in for the first part of the `WHERE` and send the `SELECT` only to the desired shard.

BTW, it appears that Fabric is being decommissioned.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! Indeed, Fabric github repo [looks abandoned](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-fabric/graphs/contributors). What's the alternative might be? We hope to avoid app-level sharding if possible

Comment: Check out Spider.  Sharding across only 3 nodes does not sound very severe; are you expecting a lot more?  What brick wall has sent you to look at sharding - CPU? I/O? disk space? something else?

Comment: Our use case is very specific actually - there is a huge amount of rows in one big table, and we can easily avoid multi-shard queries. The main goal is to scale writes and be sure indexes fit in RAM.

Comment: "Fit in RAM" because you have lots of `SELECTs`?

Comment: We want indexes to fit in RAM for performance reasons - the table is going to be huge + many fields on it have indexes

Comment: "Performance" as in thousands of queries per _second_?  Or needing results in less than 10ms?  If all you need is 200/sec and 20ms latency, sharding is not necessary.

Comment: We are targeting ~ 2000 rps submit rate with deduplication logic (which means same rate SELECTs, less rate INSERTs) and < 100 rps retrieve queries. Also horizontal scalability is our's system requirement, so actually we have to support sharding from the beggining

Comment: Did you look at `INSERT IGNORE`?  But watch out for "burning" `AUTO_INCREMENT` values.  Can you batch the dedup operation in rows of at least 100?  That would significantly improve performance.